# How to Pivot Without Aggregation, Is that possible?

Tags: sql, pivot

I want to rearrange the table with rows and columns in the following order. Is this possible and how?

[image]

This is the outcome i expect. How can I do this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your have multiple value for each row then what you expect without aggregation function?
And if you have a single value per each row, so it's no matter that use sum,min,max or avg aggregation function.
like this(in oracle):

```
select row_id, 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'
  from table 
pivot(max("value") for column_id in('C1', 'C2','C3'));
```

executable version with sample:

```
select row_id, 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'
  from (select 1 table_id, 'C1' Column_id, 1 Row_id, 20000 "value"          from dual        union all
    select 1 table_id, 'C2' Column_id, 1 Row_id, 30000 "value"          from dual        union all
    select 1 table_id, 'C3' Column_id, 1 Row_id, 25000 "value"          from dual        union all
    select 1 table_id, 'C1' Column_id, 2 Row_id, 80200 "value"          from dual        union all
    select 1 table_id, 'C2' Column_id, 2 Row_id, 50000 "value"          from dual        union all
    select 1 table_id, 'C3' Column_id, 2 Row_id, 95000 "value" from dual) 
pivot(max("value") for column_id in('C1', 'C2','C3'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Row_ID,
     Min(Case DBColumnName When 'c1' Then Value End) c1,
     Min(Case DBColumnName When 'c2' Then Value End) c2,
     Min(Case DBColumnName When 'c3' Then Value End) c3
   From table
   Group By Row_ID
```

Edit: I have written this without an editor & have not run the SQL. I hope, you get the idea.